# Copying elements from a char vector to a string vector

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector of chars and I want to copy the elements in a string vector.I want each cell of the second vector to have **k** elements of the first, forming a string. Although I have no compiling errors the programm crashes when it forms the string vector.

Thanks in advance!

```
vector<string> v2;

for(int i = 0; i <= v1.size(); i++){    //v1 is the char vector

    for(int j = 0; j <= k; j++){
        v2[i] = v2[i] + v1[j];
    }

    cout << v2[i] << endl;
}
```

Comment: `v2` size is 0. You need to add elements to it.

Comment: `i <= v1.size()` is dangerous too

Comment: btw, are you intending to have `v1.size()` identical strings, all equal to the **first** `k` characters?  Or you want it cut into non-overlapping pieces of `k` characters each?

Comment: Yep, where does `k` come from?

Comment: @BenVoigt To be more accurate lets say i have these chars{h,e,l,l,o} in v1[0] to v1[4] respectivly.I want my v2 cells to be(if k=2 for example):{he,el,ll,lo}.if k=3 the will be like:{hel,ell,llo} etc.

Comment: @LefterisMantas: So you do want overlap... Dietmar's answer is the closest to a solution to that particular problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had to make sure that your other vector has enough elements in it.

(UPDATE: using postfix operation for v2 will save memory and running time, because in that case no temporary variable has to be allocated to perform the addition operation.)

```
vector <string> v2(v1.size());
for(int i=0;i<=v1.size();i++){    //v1 is the char vector
    for (int j=0;j<=k;j++){
        v2[i]+=v1[j];
    }
cout<<v2[i]<<endl;
}
```

Comment: So, not only are you doing string concatenation the worst way possible, creating temporary variables and assigning, but now you have a bunch of empty strings at the end of v2.

Comment: I think you shouldn't confuse beginners with advanced techniques when they just start.

Comment: Well please, at least use `+=`.  Should be many times faster.

Comment: deal :) (ps I am not a beginner :-)

Comment: Well, my comment about empty strings above is wrong -- I interpreted the question totally different, and think there should be `v1.size() / k` strings.

Comment: That could make sense, the question wasn't very specific on what `k` was.

Answer (score 2):

Your vector `v2` is empty when you access `v2[i]`: this operation is, thus, illegal. You probably want something like

```
std::vector<std::string> v2;
v2.reserve(v1.size()); // optionally reserve enough elements; may improve performance
for (std::string::const_iterator it(v1.begin()), end(v1.end()); it != end; ++it) {
    v2.push_back(std::string(it, it + std::min(k, std::distance(it, end))));
    std::cout << v2.back() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: That uses `k` repetitions of each one character from `v1`.  That's not what the question means to me.

Comment: Another interesting interpretation... I wish the question were less ambiguous.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Yes, there are a number of ways this assignment can be interpreted. Another approach could be to stop if there are fewer than `k` characters left. Oddly enough the code which does out of bounds access for `k - 1` characters got accepted...

Answer (score 1):

There's a string constructor that takes a pair of iterators -- use it to grab `k` consecutive characters.  Then, start the next string where the last one ended (I think this is what your question meant?)

```
vector<string> v2;

auto p1 = v1.begin();
auto const pend = v1.end();
if (v1.size() > k) {
    auto const pendk = pend - k;
    do {
        auto const p2 = p1 + k; // locate k characters
        v2.emplace_back(p1, p2);// make a string from those characters
        p1 = p2;                // the end of this one is the start of the next
    } while (p1 < pendk);
}
if (p1 != pend)             // deal with any leftover (<= k) characters at the end
    v2.emplace_back(p1, pend);
```

Comment: Note, you can't form iterator `p1 + k` if `std::distance(p1, pend) < k`. `p1 + k` needs to be in the range `[v1.begin(), v1.end()]`.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: True.  Is this better?  (I just hate calculating that twice)

Comment: If you don't like recomputing things (nor do I for that matter) it may be reasonable to compute the end ahead of time: `for (auto begin(p1.begin()), end(k < p1.size()? p1.end() - k - 1: p1.begin()); begin < end; begin += k)`

Comment: @DietmarKühl: How's this version?